# Rails Simpleform with non-model inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I have a normal form using simpleform. Now I'd like to add an input that does not have any corresponding field in the model, it will be processed by the controller. I tried

```
<%= simple_form_for @obj do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :attr, as: :string %>   <-- should just send "attr" as post data
<% end %>
```

but this gives a `Method not found: attr_not_in_obj` error. I could obviously use the standard rails helpers, but then I will miss all of the simpleform HTML around the input, and copying doesn't quite seem right.

In short:
I'm looking for something like simpleform version of rails tag helpers, without any connection to a model. How do I add inputs that do not correspond to model attributes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why don't you add:

```
attr_accessor :attr
```

to your model's class definition? This way your code:

```
<%= f.input :attr %>
```

should work.

**OR**

If this solution isn't suitable, you can always pass some value to your `input` method directly:

```
<%= f.input :attr, input_html: {value: 'something'}  %>
```

Comment: But it doesn't really belong in the model, it's something that only the controller should be aware of.

Comment: The second option is just the default value, how does this affect the problem?

Comment: I'm looking for something like simpleform version of rails tag helpers, without any connection to a model.

Comment: @lucasclemente It solves the problem, because no call for `attr` method will be performed on `@obj` if you specified some value for it. Put `''` (empty string) instead of `'something'` if this bothers you. Just try it.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt this solution for a collection. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Nevermind... see my solution to the original question, which solved my problem (as well as @lucasclemente 's).

Comment: Wish someone had answered the original question.

Answer (score 12):

Say you wanted to use a rails form helper but still wrap it in SimpleForm goodness? You can, by calling input with a block like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @obj do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :attr do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'attr' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's a good idea but all related simple_form css classes like `boolean`, `optional` and proper id would not be set. It builds a proper label though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, below are quote from [simple_form wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes)

#### String Input

`app/inputs/fake_input.rb:`

```
class FakeInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  # This method only create a basic input without reading any value from object
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)
    template.text_field_tag(attribute_name, nil, merged_input_options)
  end
end
```

Then you can do `<%= f.input :thing, as: :fake %>`