# How to add a select without association to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, simple-form

I have a model called "Store" and it has an attribute "City" which has a "State" associated to it. I'm creating a store's filter by state and/or city with simple_form. The problem is, how to make simple_form does not associate the "State" to "Store" ?

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :state
  has_many   :stores
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :description, :city_id

   validates :city,        :presence => true
   validates :description, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 500}
   validates :latitude,    :presence => true
   validates :longitude,   :presence => true

   belongs_to :city
end


<%= simple_form_for @store, :html => { :class => 'add-store-form', :style => "display:none;" } do |f| %>
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Estado:</td>
      <td>
        <%= f.collection_select :state, State.all, :include_blank => false, :label => false, 
                              :input_html => { :id => "state_id", :name => "state_id" } %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    .
    .
```

This way is not working.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to you question, but improve your code by doing:

```
validates :city, :latitude, :longitude, :description, presence: true
validates :description, length: {maximum: 500}
```

And I recommend using `Strong Parameters (Default in rails 4)` to define with attributes can be assigned from forms instead of attr_accessible option

Comment: Solved using the checked answer of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349508/rails-simpleform-with-non-model-inputs