# can't use simple_form as: :date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

i have used well `simple_form` expect `:date` type.

```
<%= f.input :id,
            label: I18n.t('label_for_id'),
            required: false,
            input_html: {
                    size: 50,
                    value: params[:contents].try(:[], :id)
            } %>
```

this code wokrs well. but,

```
<%= f.input :dob,
            label: "Date of Birth",
            as: :date,
            start_year: Time.now.year - 90,
            end_year: Time.now.year - 8,
            order: [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

this code make an exception like,
[image]

how can i fix it?

Comment: Content doesn't have a 'dob' attribute

Comment: i know it. but `:dob` is a key of parameter(rails `params` hash). it's `id` option of html form tag

Comment: You cannot use it like this then, you can use `input_field` instead if I remember simple_form correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You should add attribute "dob" to you Content model. Because simple_form tries call "dob" on you Content object for setting value to input.

P.S.
Sorry, bad English.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but, other `simple_form` elements are work well with attribute that don't exist

Comment: @qodot No, you're wrong. Maybe you use rails form builder and input helpers. For simple form attribute is required. You can add attr_accessor if you do not want to save it in DB or specify value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349508/rails-simpleform-with-non-model-inputs