# Rails Simple Form Checkbox variable undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am creating a rails simple form which has two fields: a collection and a checkbox. The values inside the collection are determined based on whether the checkbox is selected or not.

```
<%= f.input :id, :collection => (@s if show_all_shoppers || @rs), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :label => "Shopper", :include_blank => true %>

<%= f.input :show_all_shoppers, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :input_html => { :'data-label' => 'Display all shoppers'} %>
```

But, I keep getting `undefined local variable or method show_all_shoppers` when I try this. Please note `:id` is a fieldname inside my model instance but `show_all_shoppers` is not

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly I don't know what you are trying to do but there should be some javascript executing when the checkbox is checked. In your model create a `attr_accessor` like this:

```
attr_accessor :show_all_shoppers
```

And then in your form you can do as:

```
<%= f.input :show_all_shoppers, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :input_html => { :'data-label' => 'Display all shoppers'} %>
```

There is another solution but I have never tried it so don't know will work or not:

```
<%= f.input :show_all_shoppers do %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'show_all_shoppers', 'Display all shoppers', false %>
<% end %>
```

Source: [Rails Simpleform with non-model inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349508/rails-simpleform-with-non-model-inputs)

May be you can give it a try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I don't need this value in form submit. But I get this error: undefined method `check_box_tag' for #<SimpleForm>

Comment: Actually the answer was for rails form and you are using `simple_form`, I didn't knew that. Try the updated answer

Comment: do I need to create an attr_Accessor if I don't want to use this value on form submit?

Comment: There is never `=` in `end` It would always be `<% end %>` not `<%= end %>` and regarding the `attr_accessor` I am not sure but didn't find any other alternative rather than this for `simple_form`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= check_box_tag 'show_shoppers', 'show_all_shoppers', false %><small> Show All Shoppers</small>
```

works along with edits to javascript/jquery